# font-size doesn't apply when i change it

Tags: html, css

hi guys i have an xhtml file who contains two texts which i applied a css style with contain a 'font-size' attribute who doesn't applied on my text attribute when i change it, here is my code

welcome.xhtml:

```
<ui:define  name="MyContent">
        
      
       <div class="container">
          <span class="text1" >Welcome in</span>
            <span class="text2">Developpers</span>
        </div>
        
        
    </ui:define>
```

welcome.css:

```
.container{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 90px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
.container span{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-size: 90px;
}
.text1{
 
  color: black;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 
  position: relative;
  animation: text 3s 1;
}
.text2{
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #6ab04c;
}

@keyframes text {
  0%{
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  30%{
    letter-spacing: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
  85%{
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
  }
}
```

hope it was clear.
thank you all for ur help.

Comment: What happens when you browse that page incognito? Do your changes get applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's all about CSS specificity.

### Therefore

```
.container span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    font-size: 90px;
}
```

`.container span{...}` will override the two classes below it because it has higher specificity than class alone `.text1`

So to fix it be more specific.

```
.container span.text1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    animation: text 3s 1;
}

.container span.text2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #6ab04c;
}
```

[image]

So if you are confused please use this [CSS Specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Here is the specificity level you had

[image]

As you can see  `.container span{...}` has higher specificity that's why you couldn't override its value.

But if you are more specific you surely can.

[image]

Therefore `.container span.text1` is more specific and you can override the `font-size`

I hope that was clear and answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see that you are applying a font-size in the container class, the span elements and then also the text1 and text2 classes.

So the question is, where are you changing the font-size? Are you doing it in the container class, or the CSS applied to the span element or the text1/text2 classes?

I think you are having a [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) issue here.

Also why not just apply the font-sizes in the text1 and text2. Why are you also applying it in the ".container span {}" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.container` class before text 1 & text 2 in your CSS:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GI97GLRG48VH

```css
    .container {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 90px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      width: 100%;
    }
    .container span{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: block;
      font-size: 90px;
    }
     .container .text1{
     
      color: black;
      font-size: 90px;
      font-weight: 700;
      letter-spacing: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
     
      position: relative;
      animation: text 3s 1;
    }
    .container .text2{
      font-size: 60px;
      color: #6ab04c;
    }
    
    @keyframes text {
      0%{
        color: white;
        margin-bottom: -40px;
      }
      30%{
        letter-spacing: 25px;
        margin-bottom: -40px;
      }
      85%{
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        margin-bottom: -40px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GI97GLRG48VH
 check it is okay? @YACINE kaneiky